# Why Spring Security's BCrypt implementation uses a no-early-return equals method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, equals, bcrypt

In Spring Security's BCrypt implementation, I came across the following method ([source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.0.4.RELEASE/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.java#L655)):

```java
static boolean equalsNoEarlyReturn(String a, String b) {
  char[] caa = a.toCharArray();
  char[] cab = b.toCharArray();

  if (caa.length != cab.length) {
    return false;
  }

  byte ret = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < caa.length; i++) {
    ret |= caa[i] ^ cab[i];
  }
  return ret == 0;
}
```

Why this *no-early-return* `equals` method? What benefit it has over:

```java
static boolean equals(String a, String b) {
  char[] caa = a.toCharArray();
  char[] cab = b.toCharArray();

  if (caa.length != cab.length) {
    return false;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < caa.length; i++) {
    if (caa[i] != cab[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Or even:

```java
return a.equals(b)
```

?

Is it because of a security point of view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's for security purpose, to avoid Timing attack. Even if it's not realy relevant for BCrypt it's good practice to do so. [Here is an answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/46215) with more information

Comment: Consider that you don't know the proper key. With early exit, you can first determine the key length by checking the execution time. Increase the key length until the execution length increases. great, you've finished the first step. Then, you can do it for each step of the key. Start with a, end with 0. One of these should take longer, since it has to do an extra execution of the next keyvalue (since the first matches). Great, you've found the one matching. Repeat for the next one. Etc.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it is the actual reason, but in the [original article](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/usenix99/provos/provos_html/node4.html) I found

> the key argument is a secret encryption key, which can be a user-chosen password of up to 56 bytes (including a terminating zero byte when the key is an ASCII string).

Since `byte` is 8 bit and `char` is 16 bit, the `ret |= caa[i] ^ cab[i];` is used to compare only the least significant bits.

I tried to execute

```
final char a = '\uff11';
final char b = '\u1111';

byte result = 0;
result |= a ^ b;
```

And `result` is `0`.

I think the reason could be that only ASCII passwords are accepted, or UTF 8 (or other charsets) are treated as ASCII chars.

Comment: 1. The reason is to prevent timing attacks. If the attacker tries passwords and gets a longer delay he knows he has guessed part of the of the password and then keeps that and changes the next character. Timing attacks are real and used in many places. 2.  is not 16-bits but is a character. 3. The developers of bcrypt were cryptographic experts, they did not make a bush-league error. 4. You have much to learn, [Grasshopper](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Grasshopper).

Comment: @zaph yes, I'm here to learn! Thank you very much! (btw char is 16 bit in java, and `|` and `^` are bitwise operations among `int`s, and that operation only compares the lowest part of the chars)

Comment: Note that the bcrypt format only contains ASCII characters, past the prefix which contains $ and a ASCII letter the rest is Base64 encoded which is also all ASCII. ASCII only used the lower 7 bits so that is all that needs to be compared. It is the hash that is being compared. Here is the thing: when you run across something that seems wrong yet is well accepted try to figure out the misunderstanding.

Comment: @zaph Yes, now I get it, I missed that the two strings arrives at that method in base64 encoding, now it's clear. Of course I never thought it was wrong, just thinking why is implemented like that, thanks a lot for the clear explanations